# What should i do to give an attribute to 180 WooCommerce products in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add filter by rating for my WooCommerce products store, i am using an image for rating on each of my products in the short description, and i have around 180 products. And i forgot to even add an option to filter by rating in my store.

I can add attributes for ratings one by one on all my products, but that would take a longtime to do.

So is there any tricks i can do to quickly finish the job?
My images in my short description have names like 4.7.png, 4.8.png, is it possible to get these image names and add them automatically in the attributes.

[Link](http://saletrons.com/store/)

Thanks.

Comment: A possible way: Apply the rating to one of your products and check how it's stored in the database. Then build an SQL query to update all your products based on this learning. Please, use a dump of your real database for testing.

Comment: Give it a try: https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to add an taxonomy/attribute for rating (from backend or admin panel) let say you have added "Rating" so `slug` will be `pa_rating`.
after adding the attribute you have to add the term/value to it, let say you have added 5.0, 4.5 so the slug will be `5-0` and `4-5` respectively.

Now copy paste the below function to your `function.php` file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files. then **run your site only for one time then delete the below code**.

```
add_action('wp', 'wh_addRatingtoProduct');
function wh_addRatingtoProduct() {

    $args = ['post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1];
    $loop = new WP_Query($args);

    if (!empty($loop->posts)):
        $attribute_name = 'pa_rating'; //slug of the attribute(taxonomy) with prefix 'pa_'
        foreach ($loop->posts as $post) :
            $content = $post->post_content; //getting product content
            $product_id = $post->ID;
            //for 5 star
            if (strpos($content, "5.0.png") !== false) {
                $attribute_value = '5'; //slug of the attribute value (term)
            }
            //for 4.7 star
            elseif (strpos($content, "4.7.png") !== false) {
                $attribute_value = '4-7'; //slug of the attribute value (term)
            }
            //for 4.8 star
            elseif (strpos($content, "4.8.png") !== false) {
                $attribute_value = '4-8'; //slug of the attribute value (term)
            }
            //...
            //...

            //Appending term to the object/product.
            $term_taxonomy_ids = wp_set_object_terms($product_id, $attribute_value, $attribute_name, true);
            $data = [
                $attribute_name => [
                    'name' => $attribute_name,
                    'value' => '',
                    'is_visible' => '1',
                    'is_variation' => '0',
                    'is_taxonomy' => '1'
                ]
            ];
            //getting the Post Meta
            $_product_attributes = get_post_meta($product_id, '_product_attributes', TRUE);
            //Updating the Post Meta
            update_post_meta($product_id, '_product_attributes', array_merge($_product_attributes, $data));
        endforeach;
    endif;
}
```

**Replace all the `$attribute_value` with the desired slug of attribute value.
before doing this it is very strongly recommended to take a database backup.**

Code is tested and works.

Reference: [Add Attribute to WooCommerce Product Programmatically](http://www.webhat.in/add-attribute-to-woocommerce-product-programmatically/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, but i don't know how to add all this stuff into my site, i don't know coding. Can you explain for me how to do this, like for a not learnt guy.

Comment: which plugin you are going to use to filter by product rating? because that is more important to know, and also if possible can you share your web site URL?

Comment: I am using the WooCommerce Layerd Nav widget, [link](http://saletrons.com/store/)

Comment: @DragoonShimizu: I have updated my answer, but remember to run this function only once. and don't forget to take a db backup.

Comment: This only works if you already have custom attributes already on the product. Add `if(!is_array($_product_attributes)) $_product_attributes=array();` after calling `get_post_meta` and before calling `update_post_meta`.

Answer (score 1):

Here a way by using WP Functions:

```
$products = get_posts( array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,       
    'post_type'        => 'product',        
) );

foreach ( $products as $product ) {

    $excerpt = $product->post_excerpt;
    $rating = false;

    if ( preg_match( "/2-5\.jpg/", $excerpt ) ) {
        $rating = 2;
    } else if ( preg_match( "/4-5\.jpg/", $excerpt ) ) {
        $rating = 4;
    } else if ( other cases ) ...

    if ( ! $rating ) continue;

    $attributes = DONT_KNOW; // here you have to look which data format you must provide    

    update_post_meta( $product->ID, '_product_attributes', $attributes );

}
```

Don't forget to make a database backup before. It is possible that you overwrite other product attributes. You have to chekout the right format for it.

Comment: I know, but in his question he' talking about attributes for this. Maybe he doesn't want to use `_wc_average_rating`. I don't know. I just wanted to show a way with WP Functions.

Comment: Yes i am talking about attributes, you can see this in [my site](http://saletrons.com/store/)

Comment: Sorry @AndyTschiersch I misunderstood the question.